# Angular typeahead with RxJs switchMap subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

Using [Angular bootstrap Typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples) plugin to show colours. But I need to resolve the circular references like in the other places I used. I cant make it with RxJs SwitchMap operator. Is there any other possible way to resolve?

`(<any>window).resolveJsonReferences(this.colorService.searchColors(term))`

**Typeahead with RxJs SwitchMap**

```
 search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
    .debounceTime(200)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .do(() => this.searching = true)
    .switchMap(term =>
        this.colorService.searchColors(term) // Json result needs circular reference resolver
        .do(() => this.searchFailed = false)
        .catch(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return Observable.of([]);
        }))
    .do(() => this.searching = false);
```

**In Other places**

```
return this.colorService.searchColors(term)
        .subscribe(
        res => {               
            this.colors= this.utilities.resolveJsonReferences(res);
        },
        err => {               
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `map` the value through your resolver.

```js
.map((term) => this.utilities.resolveJsonReferences(term))
```

All together:

```js
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
    .debounceTime(200)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .do(() => this.searching = true)
    .switchMap(term =>
        this.colorService.searchColors(term) // Json result needs circular reference resolver
        .map((term) => this.utilities.resolveJsonReferences(term))
        .do(() => this.searchFailed = false)
        .catch(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return Observable.of([]);
        }))
    .do(() => this.searching = false);
```

Comment: Thanks :) Happy Coding